# slow animation in a react native flatlist card

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList that contains cards, and in each card I have a nested component that shows a button with animation on click (similar to instagram like), when I added a dispatch to OnPress event I manage to update the GlobalContext but I noticed that the animation become too slow, and after debugging, I found that all the cards are re-rendered, can someone guide me to resolve this performence issue

Here is the code

FlatList.js

```
class FlatListScreen extends Component {
  static contextType = GlobalContext;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

   addItemToFavoriteList = (item) => {
    let { favoriteDispatch } = this.context;
    favoriteDispatch({
    type: ADD_TO_FAVORITE,
    payload: item,
  });
  };

  renderRow = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <CardItem
        addToFavoriteList={() => this.addItemToFavoriteList(item)}
      />
    );
  };
  ...

}
```

FavoriteButton.js

```
const FavoriteButton = ({
  itemClicked,
  color = "red",
 
}) => {
  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false);

  const toggleFavorite = () => {
    setFavorite(!favorite);
    itemClicked();
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => toggleFavorite()}
    >
      <MaterialCommunityIcons
        name={favorite ? "heart" : "heart-outline"}
        color={favorite ? "green" : "red"}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>

    ...
}
```

CardItem.js

```
class CardItem extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


   render() {
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: this.props.image }} />
          <View>
              <FavoriteButton
                itemClicked={this.props.addToFavoriteList}
                
              />

              ...

      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

   }
}
```

Provider.js

```
export const GlobalContext = createContext({});

const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [favorites, favoriteDispatch] = useReducer(favoriteReducer, []);

  const contextValue = useMemo(
    () => [favorites, favoriteDispatch],
    [favorites, favoriteDispatch]
  );

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default GlobalProvider;
```

Comment: Can you share some code snippets to better understand what this is about?

Comment: @Kenshinman here code snippet

Comment: @Kenshinman this is the rest of the code, please can you guide me to some solutions